# cdn with nginx - redirect back if not found

Tags: redirection, nginx, cdn

I need to configure cdn with nginx for images. GeoIp is working fine, but i have a problem with images that are not found on `cdn server`.

I configured nginx the following way: 
Client requests the image from server1, server1 checks if the client is from "UK" is yes redirect to `CDN server`. but now lets say the image is not found on `CDN server` server how can i redirect back to `server1` if `CDN server` is also from "UK". this will enter to endless loop...

Answer (score 1):

With a strategically-placed `rewrite` directive, you can append `$uri` with a parameter on the progress of redirects, and check for this parameter to decide whether or not to redirect back to CDN.

Or you could also use `proxy_set_header` directive when doing a request from the CDN back onto the main server1 site, and check for the existence of such HTTP header when processing requests on the main server1 site.